# copy all tables from a database to another database in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL Workbench, I have different databases and I want to copy all the tables from those databases to a new database called `newDB`, I don't have access to the root account, but I have user and password for every database by separate, I've exported correctly all the tables using the `Data Export Wizard` within `MySQL Workbench`, but when I'm in the `newDB` tab and I try to import the tables from one of the other databases using the `Data Import Wizard` I'm receiving this error:

`ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'userNewDB'@'%' to database 'db1'`

The error message is very clear, I'm under `newDB` tab in `MySQL Workbench` and is trying to import those tables from a different database that doesn't recognize that username, is there any way that I could do this using a query and passing as parameters the user and password for `db1`? Let's say that the user for `db1` is `userdb1` and the password is `passdb1`. Is that possible or it is mandatory to do this under the `root` account that I don't have access to...

Answer (score 0):

Grant all privileges to the user first:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```